# How to toggle a specific div class inside loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm finding no exact word to make you understand. I better show you my code:

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

<button class="btn<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Button</button>
<p hidden class="area<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni beatae vero perspiciatis atque praesentium animi, non? Voluptatem, tempora fugiat quos animi facilis facere obcaecati enim reiciendis excepturi sunt! Ducimus, modi!
</p>

<?php } ?>


<script>
    $('.btn').click(function(){   // Can't set the specific number beside .btn
        $('.area').show(); // Can't set the specific number beside .area
    });
</script>
```

I want to make my work done for specific class. No idea how I can get the exact classname from  and 



 tag.

> I expect:

```
<script>
    $('.btn1').click(function(){
        $('.area1').show();
    });

    $('.btn2').click(function(){
        $('.area2').show();
    });

    $('.btn3').click(function(){
        $('.area3').show();
    });

    --------------- and so on -------------
</script>
```

Hope you understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the exact HTML, assign a common class i.e. `btn` and `area` and then use DOM relationship to target the desired element.

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<p class="area">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni beatae vero perspiciatis atque praesentium animi, non? Voluptatem, tempora fugiat quos animi facilis facere obcaecati enim reiciendis excepturi sunt! Ducimus, modi!
</p>
```

*Script*

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.area').toggle();
});
```

---

However if you don't have the exact HTML, you can still use a common class to bind event handler using custom `data-*` attribute.

```
<button class="btn" data-target=".area<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Button</button>
<p class="area<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni beatae vero perspiciatis atque praesentium animi, non? Voluptatem, tempora fugiat quos animi facilis facere obcaecati enim reiciendis excepturi sunt! Ducimus, modi!
</p>
```

then use

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: But how can i get **$row['id']** in jquery function ?